# Jquery ajax error - Requests adding GET var

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

My ajax function has stopped working all of a sudden.

```
function get_file_info()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/includes/get_file_info.php",
        dataType: "json",
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: "callbackName",
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
        }
    });  
}
```

I did some debugging and found that the ajax request is going to

```
http://localhost/includes/get_file_info.php?_=1297356964250
```

I am just would like to know what it is and can be used for, also how to remove so the ajax request is like below so it works again.

```
http://localhost/includes/get_file_info.php
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I think I read somewhere that this is a new feature in jQuery 1.5. Are you using 1.5? However, that parameter should not break your request. What makes you think it does?

Comment: Try just using the path name for your directory (i.e. "includes/get_file_info.php")

Comment: @Pekka Yes I am using v1.5. The page it is requesting will redirect to the main page if any GET vars are passed.

Comment: @tkm256 Yes I have tried that also. Thanks

Comment: @Michael ah. Hmmmm... I'm sure this can be turned off in jQuery but I would tend to change the server side behaviour instead - if that is possible at all

Comment: @Pekka Im sure you can too. Changing server side would me loads of editing and then its a chain reaction 1 things effects another. Would rather change 1 line ;)

Comment: @Michael yeah, I can understand that. But that redirecting behaviour is pretty prone to breaking, which is why I think it wouldn't hurt to limit it to the actual valid cases somehow.

Answer (score 2):

If you add:

`cache: true,`

to your call it will remove the timestamp which is there to always call a different URL's so the browser doesn't cache the result. This is standard for calls except for datatypes `script` and `jsonp`.

As others have stated though, it would be good to change the server side to stop turning away anything with GET's, maybe check if the get is a `_` and only `numeric`, if not then turn it away...

Answer (score 0):

The "_=1297356964250" query string is jQuery's method of preventing the URL being cached and returning an old result. Adding this ensures that you're retrieving a new response every time.

This is not the cause of your request breaking down. It must be from another issue. Have you tried logging your response and seeing what it returns?

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: He said in the comments that his script redirects to another page when there is something in the query string.

Comment: Thanks for explaing what it is and does, makes sense :) I know its loading the error for when if GET data is present. I edited the function to hide urls etc. Its using urls like controller/method/view so if GET data is sent it treats it as an error. So there is no way of doing this or it would be risky as might get an old page load?

Comment: You could pass 'cache: true' in the ajax object (as detailed here in the docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) but you do run the risk of getting a cached response.